# Utilizing an associative array while constructing an object

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not too experienced with PHP, but I'm trying to create a small program that will utilize a class schedule and print out statements based on what time each class is, etc.

Here is my program that I have a question about:

```
class Period {
    public $name;
    public $times = array(); //Ideally, whatever is inputted here will be an array.

    public function __construct($name, $times) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->times = $times;
    }
}
$A_Block = new Period("AP Graphic Design", ("Day 1"=>"8:20", "Day 2"=>"11:35", "Day 4"=>"2:10", "Day 5"=>"10:20","Day 7"=>"1:10"));
```

I have the period class with two attributes, a simple name string, and an associative array (dictionary) of times that the class occurs. During the initialization of $A_Block, something is wrong with how I'm creating the array.

What will I need to change in my Period class in order to be able to create the A_Block class with the associative array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array syntax is wrong: that should be:

```
$A_Block = new Period("AP Graphic Design", array("Day 1"=>"8:20", ... ));
```

Or, using the newer array syntax:

```
$A_Block = new Period("AP Graphic Design", ["Day 1"=>"8:20", .... ]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe the issue was that simple. For some reason I was thinking that having array() while creating the object was incorrect.

Comment: Glad to help! :-) You can read the gory details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: I meant to add that, if the second parameter in the constructor is always an array, you can use a type hint: `public function __construct($name, array $times) { ... }` - this will throw an exception if anything but an array is passed in. Good habits and all that...